Filtering out rows that don’t fit the schema in pyspark
I have a file named employee.csv with columns empid as integer and empname string. I am reading the files into a dataframe d1 by defining the schema and reading into another dataframe d2 as it is. The employee.csv has the data as below:
01,A\n
02,B\n
3,C\n
D,d\n

I want to list out rows where the empid is not an integer. I converted the column empid to integer in d2 to find out the badrows by using subtract but now I see the row D,d coming as null,d as the output of the subtract command. How do I get the desired out.
I also tried to filter out rows that fails to cast into integer but that doesn't seem to work either.
d3 = d2.filter(d2[“empid”].cast(“int”).isNull())

Please let me know how do we achieve it.

This question is similar to: How to check if a string column in pyspark dataframe is all numeric. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To return a list of empid's that are not integers you can use filter()
and isdigit():
out = d2.filter(~d2['empid'].astype(str).str.isdigit()).tolist()

